# Strange behavior with all projects Entity Framework and Model Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am having some really strange behavior. Maybe I am missing something. The last thing I can remember doing before this error occured was installing VS 2012 RC1. Tried removing Entity from my project and adding an older version. Also tried a brand new project from scratch with no avail. Big problem now is that when I deploy just the project dll, it gives the same error on production as developing locally. So I am pretty sure it is not tied to my working environment or something I installed. Anyway here are the errors generated from Entity and I cannot find any solutions. Please can you pass your wisdom as I need to make some changes to production code and cant seem to get around the error below.

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'UrlHelper' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'RequestContext' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'HttpContextBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Exception' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Type' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'AssemblyName' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'CultureInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'DateTimeFormatInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Calendar' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'IdentityReference' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'RouteData' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'RouteBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ControllerContext' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ControllerBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: The specified name is not allowed: '__ConsoleStream'.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Encoding' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'TextWriter' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet �ActionResults� for End �ContentResult_ContentEncoding_Source� could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet �ActionResults� for End �JsonResult_ContentEncoding_Source� could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �UrlHelpers� is based on type �UrlHelper� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �RequestContexts� is based on type �RequestContext� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �HttpContextBases� is based on type �HttpContextBase� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Exceptions� is based on type �Exception� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Types� is based on type �Type� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �AssemblyNames� is based on type �AssemblyName� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �CultureInfoes� is based on type �CultureInfo� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �DateTimeFormatInfoes� is based on type �DateTimeFormatInfo� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Calendars� is based on type �Calendar� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �IdentityReferences� is based on type �IdentityReference� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �RouteDatas� is based on type �RouteData� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �RouteBases� is based on type �RouteBase� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ControllerContexts� is based on type �ControllerContext� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ControllerBases� is based on type �ControllerBase� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Encodings� is based on type �Encoding� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �TextWriters� is based on type �TextWriter� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ActionResults� is based on type �ActionResult� that has no keys defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid! I created a model inheriting from my controller. So Entity was trying to create a table based on my controller properties. Sometimes the most basic programming mistakes take you the longest to solve.

```
public class MyClass : Controller
```

Instead of

```
public class MyClass
```